# Unexpected formatting - CSS using images in a <div>

Tags: css

I have a div say

```
<div id='abc' style='overflow:auto;width:20px'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

The scroll here works just fine , and i can see a scroll bar(horizontal)

However , when , i replace the text aaaaa... by an image , so that the same image is repeated a number of times , it actually extends into the next line , and doesn't give me an enabled scroll bar

Why is this happening ?

I'd really appreciate any help with this

Thanks

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle demo of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the white-space property of the div to `white-space:nowrap`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5EpXD/)**

```
div{
  white-space:nowrap;
}​
```

Comment: To add some explanation: With the `aaaaa...` a single “word” is being displayed which cannot wrap on multiple lines. If you replaced that by `aaa aaa aaa aaa...` you would have seen that it would wrap just like the images did. Now, multiple images are not a “word” but include boundaries that allow them to be wrapped to multiple lines. So you get the effect you’ve seen.